# Dafny set var to never change

Tags: dafny

Is there a way in dafny to set a `var` and say once it is set it will never change?

Currently I have a class that looks like

```
class {:autocontracts} Test
{
    var max: nat

    constructor(maxVal: nat)
        ensures max == maxVal
    {
        max := maxVal;
    }

    // predicate Valid()...
    
    // all my other methods
}
```

My issue is that to get some aspects of the class working, I have to specify `ensures max == old(max)` for every method. Is there a way to say to dafny that `max` will never change once the constructor has set it so that I don't need to do the ensures after every method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the field using `const` instead of `var`.